# change value of data sent to ajax call in complete function

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I need to change the data sent to ajax call on complete function.

Lets say I set `var total = 1;` after that ajax call started

```
function test(total) {
    total = total;
    alert("total : " + total);
}
$('#call_analysis_basic_table').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 100,
    "ajax":{
        type: "POST",
        url :"http://localhost:8050/phpservice/index.php", // json datasource
        data: {
            "rec" : total,
            "phone" : "d123",
            "from_date" : "14-05-2016" ,
            "to_date" : "20-09-2017"
        },
        error: function(){  
            alert("error");
        },
        complete: function(data){  
            total = data.responseJSON.recordsTotal;
            test(total);
        }
    }
} );
```

First time the value of parameter `rec` will be `1`, in the end I changed the value of total in complete function (Lets say value of total is 20 now) .
But when I click on page 2 of table, the ajax call started, and it again sent the value of rec to 1, and not sending 20 ?
Why is it happening, I change the value of parameter in complete function but still in next ajax call, it gets the old value of parameter ?

Comment: Set the value outside the scope should work.

Comment: @TGarrett how? I spent my last 2 hour on this already. I am new to javascript

Comment: Well, you mentioned page changes? then store a value in localStorage, and get that value u stored and update it. If there are no page changes, google js scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` value can be a function, which will be called to return the data that's sent to the server:

```
data: function(d) {
    return $.extend({}, d, {
        "rec" : total,
        "phone" : "d123",
        "from_date" : "14-05-2016" ,
        "to_date" : "20-09-2017"
    };
},
```

This will use the updated value of `total`.

See the `ajax.data` [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data).

Comment: Can you please tell me how to convert these values by `JSON.stringify` and then pass these values to data attribute ?

Comment: You can't convert a function to JSON.